# Finger print login in IONIC 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic2 app which uses fingerprint authentication to login the app. However the API allows all the users who has access to device to login. I need to restrict the user login to specific user who has access to the devices. How to match the fingerprint to the specific user rather than allowing everyone having access to device?

Comment: The fingerprint only returns if it is ok or not.

Comment: Actually the only thing you can check is if the given fingerprint is from the devices' owner.